# Having issue accessing images inside jar (java swing)

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, executable-jar

First I know that there already exists lots of topics on how to access the image inside the jar file.I tried many options and none of them worked. I have created one java swing application using Intellij IDE. The app has many images used in the panels as well as tables. These images are displayed properly when I run my project inside Intellij. But when i create the JAR it executes fine but the images are missing. However, when I put the images in the same directory as the JAR file the images are properly displayed.Is there a way to package everything in a JAR? I packaged Sounds folder for now and it actually works for the sounds but for images it doesn't. **1 MIN VIDEO OF HOW IT LOOKS:**  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4lCRljlZqY&ab_channel=GMdz0ji

I looked many answers on the Internet and nothing worked for me. I am displaying image like this  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/logoNewLogin.png");    Here is my project structure

```
- src
        - main
                - java
                - resources
                      - Images/  (multiple images)
                      - Sounds/  (multiple .mp4 sounds)
```

Also lots of answers for obtaining the image which i saw were something like this (maybe i did this wrong but this was indeed an answer)

```
class A{
public static void main(String[] args){                                                                         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon();
    try {
      image.setImage((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(A.class.getResource("/images/"+imageName))));
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Image Error: " + ex);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You state `- Images/  (multiple images)` as the path, but then use `"/images/"+imageName` in your code ... I would also unzip the resulting Jar and manually verify that the images have been bundled with the Jar (I know you state you know they exist, but unless you've done that one step, you don't know that they are available at runtime - just saying)

Comment: I would also use `ImageIO.read` over `ImageIcon` as `ImageIO` will throw an exception if the image can't be read, unlike `ImageIcon` which fails silently

Comment: I unzipped and the images folder with images was present.However resources folder itself was missing but those folders from inside are present in uzipped jar.

Comment: So regarding Exception.I was also wondering why for some reason it doesn't throw it.It's like he doesn't recognise it but did find it

Comment: *"However resources folder itself was missing but those folders from inside are present in uzipped jar"* - Yes, you should NOT have a `resource` folder in the Zip, only the `Images` and `Sounds` folders, also remember, the path names a case sensitive, so `images != Images`

Comment: `ImageIcon` and `Toolkit.getImage` don't throw exceptions, this is because the `Image` class attempts to load the image in it's own thread, so these return immediately, but they might not yet be "realised" (ie fully loaded).  This is why I recommend using `ImageIO.read` instead.  It will either throw an exception or return a fully realised image.  Just beware, it might impact the responsiveness of your code, as the images are loaded within the current thread

Comment: I tried it now.It also doesnt work :/ .I will record a quick 2min video of what i am doing and post the link here maybe you will see something which i don't

Comment: *I am displaying image like this ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/logoNewLogin.png");* That's wrong, as it means you're accessing it as a *file*. Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: Here is the link to the video.It is 1min long  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4lCRljlZqY&ab_channel=GMdz0ji

Comment: `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(A.class.getResource("/Images/logoNewLogin.png")); ` should do it for you

Comment: @g00se i tried it.It works when run from Intellij but when packaged still nothing.

Comment: That's very strange. It suggests Images is not at the root. You therefore need to post a listing of the jar *formatted as code* `jar tf thejar.jar`

Comment: Ok here it is.It's a bit big so i made link to pastebin tool.Here is all of my output:  https://pastebin.com/UVCcQGCk

Comment: Links and pastebins and videos are of no interest whatsoever. Questions here must be &self-contained.*

Comment: OK, out of interest, which class is it *actually* that uses the code I posted?

Comment: MainClient.java (for now because i can't even make this one load the image)

Comment: How about `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MainClient.class.getResource("Images/logoNewLogin.png"));`?

Comment: This is what i wrote   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MainClient.class.getResource("/Images/logoNewLogin.png"));   only difference is that i have a leading / in front of images

Comment: It shouldn't really matter in this case, but try it without

Comment: @g00se you were right this is an answer   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MainClient.class.getResource("Images/logoNewLogin.png"));  i needed to clean cache of my project and do mvn clean + compile and and also error was in another class so please post it as an answer so i can give u credit for it.Tnx man!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'm not sure my comment really qualifies for archiving as an answer, so I'll leave it for now